# Posix shared memory initialization

Tags: c, linux, unix, posix, shared-memory

My question is regarding initializing memory obtained from using `shm_open()` and `mmap()`.  One common advice I have seen in several places is to call `shm_open()` with flags `O_CREAT|O_EXCL`: if that succeeds then we are the first user of the shared memory and can initialize it, otherwise we are not the first and the shared memory has already been initialized by another process.

However, from what I understand about `shm_open` and from the testing that I did on Linux, this wouldn't work: the shared memory objects get left over in the system, even after the last user of the shared memory object has unmapped and closed.  A simple test program which calls `shm_open` with `O_CREAT|O_EXCL`, then closes the descriptor and exit, will succeed on the first run, but will still fail on the second run, even though nobody else is using the shared memory at that time.

It actually seems to me that (at least on the system that I tested) the behavior of `shm_open` is pretty much identical to `open()`: if I modify my simple test program to write something to the shared memory (through the pointer obtained by `mmap`) and exit, then the shared memory object will keep its contents persistently (I can run another simple program to read back the data I wrote previously).

So is the advice about using `shm_open` with `O_CREAT|O_EXCL` just wrong, or am I missing something?

I do know that the shared memory object can be removed with `shm_unlink()`, but it seems that will only cause more problems:

1. If a process dies before calling `shm_unlink()` then we are back to the problem described above.
2. If one process calls `shm_unlink()` while some other processes are still mapped into the same shared memory, these other processes will still continue using it as usual.  Now, if another process comes and calls `shm_open()` with the same name and `O_CREAT` specified, it will actually succeed in creating new shared memory object with the same name, which is totally unrelated to the old shared memory object the other processes are still using.   Now we have a process trying to communicate with other processes via the shared memory and totally unaware that it is using a wrong channel.

I m used to Windows semantics where shared memory object exists only as long as at least one handle is open to it, so this Posix stuff is very confusing.

Comment: It looks like you don't set up your shm segment for deletion when you are done with it. Thus, it _survives_ your process. You can use `ipcs` command in a terminal to see what kind of _IPC_ stuff (semaphore, shm segments and so on) are currently alive in your system.

Comment: But how do i set it up for deletion?  Is there some flag to pass to shm_open()?  I couldn't find anything on the manpage.

Comment: @Rerito: Any ideas on the OP's comment to your comment?

Comment: In an actual use case of Shared Memory, the two processes that might share the same segment will be _alive_ at the same time. Then, there is no reason not to call `shm_unlink()` when needed.

Comment: Since I made some assumptions in my answer, could you give us more info about the reason you are using shared memory ?

Comment: If your share memory with only child processes, you can use `shm_open()` to obtain descriptor and `shm_unlink()` it right after. Then you can share descriptor over `fork()`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you use the `O_EXCL` flag I will assume that you have a set of processes gathered around one master (the creator of the segment).

Then, your master process will create the shared memory segment using a call to `shm_open` :

```
shmid = shm_open("/insert/name/here", O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0644);
if (-1 == shmid) {
    printf("Oops ..\n");
}
```

Here, the slaves are ready to use the segment. Since the master HAS to create the segment, there is no need to use the `O_CREAT` flag in the slaves calls. You'll just have to handle possible errors if the slave call is performed when the segment is not created yet or already destroyed.

When any of your processes is done with the segment, it should call `shm_unlink()`. In this kind of architecture, the *master* is usually feeding the *slaves*. When it has nothing more to say, it just shuts up. The *slaves* have then the responsibility to handle corresponding errors gracefully.

As you stated, if a process dies *before* calling the `shm_unlink` procedure, then the segment will continue to live thereafter. To avoid this in some cases, you could define your own signal handlers in order to perform the operation when signals such as `SIGINT` are received. Anyway, you won't be able to cover the mess in case `SIGKILL` is sent to your process.

EDIT :
To be more specific, the use of `O_CREAT | O_EXCL` is wrong when unnecessary. With the little example above, you can see that it is required for the master to create the segment, thus those flags are needed. On the other hand, none of the slave processes would have to ever create it. Thus, you will absolutely forbid the use of `O_CREAT` in the related calls.

Now, if another process calls `shm_open(..., O_CREAT, ...)` when the segment is already created, it will just retrieve a file descriptor related to this very segment. It will thus be on the right channel (if it has the rights to do so, see the `mode` argument)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  In my case, however, the process doesn't know if it is a "master" or "slave".  The whole problem here is to find out which one it is.  Basically, once the process maps to the shared memory, it needs the answer to the question "Am I first?" and if so, call initialization routine.  Because a process might be killed (if it is with SIGKILL, we can't intercept it), we can't really assume that existence of the shared memory segment in the file system means anything at all.

Comment: I have a solution in mind using a file lock to ensure correct shared memory initialization (it actually uses 2 file locks to avoid certain race conditions).  However there are some doubts about it, again related to abnormal process termination.  I posted the relevant question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19674214/resource-cleanup-on-abnormal-process-termination

Comment: @YevgeniyP Usually, semaphores are used along with shared memory to ensure proper use. But, again, you can't prevent the good behavior of your process set if some of them get killed (with SIGKILL). Anyway I can't find any solution to this now ...

Comment: Yeah, i can't find solution that behaves correctly under all circumstances.  Windows is better in that regard - it guarantees that for the first user of the shared memory segment, the segment will be initialized with zeros (unless its backed by a real file of course). So in Windows i could just write some flag after initialization is done and then other processes could check it (e.g. whether the first byte is 0 or not).  Posix does not seem to have that, especially if the segment was left on the file system after a process got killed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following :
int test = shmget(key_t key,size,0);   Put this at the star of each process. Zero flag here tries to open an existing shared memory if its not created yet test will equal -1 so you can make a check after this statement if test -1 go and creat a shared memory else you just got an id to an existing shared memory ..... I hope this help

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, you might want to open with `O_CREAT | O_TRUNC`  to wipe the data clean?  And/or perhaps reset your memory map data via explicit assignments to the struct members?

On another note, you may opt to control for the "master" by tracking a pid in shared memory (or just a temp file), and then validate if that pid is still valid.